# How can I get non exist query condition in Django queryset __in cluase

Tags: django, django-queryset

Assume I have a queryset: `Book.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3,4,5])`. Is there any easy way(i.e. built-in API) to get which pk does not correspond to any record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
pk_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
books_pk = Book.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).values_list('pk', flat=True)
invalid_pk = list(set(pk_list) - set(books_pk))
```

The code is self explanatory. Let me know if you need explanation.